# Time comparison in java

Tags: java

I would like to compare the string time format, For example
Is there any other api provided by someone?

```
public void test() {

    Stirng t1 = "10:30 AM"; // 12-hours format
    Stirng t2 = "11:30 AM"; // 12-hours format
            <or>
    Stirng t1 = "10:30"; // 24-hours format
    Stirng t2 = "11:30"; // 24-hours format

    if(t1.before(t2)) {
        System.out.println(t1 + " is before of " + t2);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309558/java-time-comparison

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use [Joda Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) to parse the time and perform comparisons.

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to compare the string time format

Don't, unless you *really* have to.

In general - and this is something that has become clearer to me over time, watching *many* Stack Overflow questions - the sooner you can get your data into a "natural" format, the better. In this case, the natural data format is something representing a time of day, *not* a string.

So parse all your strings - ideally using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) and its [`DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseLocalTime%28java.lang.String%29) method to create [`LocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) objects. Then they will be naturally comparable, and also usable for anything else you want to do. Keep the data in its natural form for as long as you can, only converting it to a string or other representation when you absolutely *have* to, e.g. for serialization to another machine.

Of course, if you can avoid having a string representation *at all* that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Try [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/),

For your example it would be

```
if (new DateTime(2012, 9, 15, 10, 30).compareTo(new DateTime(2012, 9, 15, 11, 30) < 0) {
    // first is before second date
}
```

EDIT: after Jon's advice

This would be better

```
if (new LocalTime(10, 30).compareTo(new LocalTime(11, 30) < 0) {
    // first time is before second time
}
```

Comment: `DateTime` isn't an appropriate type to use here - there's no date component, and we don't know the time zone. We have a time of day, which is represented by `LocalTime` in Joda Time.

Comment: ah thanks @JonSkeet, I didnt know about LocalTime.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about any api for that, but you can convert your string to date

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date time =  formatter.parse("11:30");
```

then just call method `time.compareTo(otherTime)`

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a") : the small letter 'a' would also enable the parsing of AM/PM

Comment: right, and if you want to be more precise, hours can be HH(0-23)/hh(0-11)/KK(1-24)/kk(1-12)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Joda Time`

`DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalTime` method gives the time object corresponding to the local time zone.

**See this link:**

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/