# Android check if time is equals

Tags: android

I am trying to create a scheduler in android. Can anyone please help me out on how i can compare a given time with current time? For example current_time = "14:00:00".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309558/time-comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
String yourTime = "14:00:00";
//get your today date as string
String today = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format(
            "hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date());

//Convert the two time string to date formate
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date date1 = sdf.parse(yourTime);
Date date2 = sdf.parse(today);

//do the comparison
if (date1.before(date2)) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it using `compareTo()` method which
Compare the receiver to the specified Date to determine the relative ordering.

```
Date selectedDate= new Date(selectedMilli);
Date currentDate= new Date();
int i = selectedDate.compareTo(currentDate);
```

Parameters

```
date  a Date to compare against.
```

Returns

```
an int < 0 if this Date is less than the specified Date, 0 if they are equal, and an int > 0 if this Date is greater.
```