# Count if 24 hours passed or not

Tags: android

I am beginner in Android. In my application i want to check if 24 hours passed or not.

I tried code from this 
article:[How to count that 24 Hours passed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243910/how-to-count-that-24-hours-passed-or-not) , but when i changed Data and Time settings in my phone, toast still doesn't work. Thanks for help

```
   // Save current time
    long savedMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

   // Check time elapsed
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= savedMillis + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"ABC",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Actually those are separated cases. Let me answer that question below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, try this

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
long nextTime = sp.getLong("nextTime", 0);
// Check time elapsed
if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= nextTime) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"ABC",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putLong("nextTime", (System.currentTimeMillis() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Derek, but now toast is always displayed when the application is starting (no matter if the date in the settings will be changed)

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake. I have updated the answer. Check now.

Comment: Thank you very much @Derek, now it works perfectly:), Could you tell me why the "old" version from my post doesn't worked?

Comment: Your `savedMillis` is an instance value which gets cleared as soon as the method call ends. You need to save the value till the next method call which can be achieved either by saving to sharedpreference or database.

Comment: Ok, Thank you one more time:)