# How do you compare Day of week and Time in Java

Tags: java, sorting, datetime

How do you compare "Friday 2:00 PM" against "Thursday 4:00 PM" in Java?

Input array:
Friday 2:00 PM
Thursday 2:00 AM
Saturday 4:00 PM

Output:
Thursday 2:00 AM
Friday 2:00 PM
Saturday 4:00 PM

Comment: Why do you put Thursday before Friday? What if they are on different weeks?

Comment: This link should help you figure it out: https://www.google.ca/search?q=how+to+compare+day+of+the+week+and+time+in+java&oq=how+to+compare+day+of+the+week+and+time+in+java&aqs=chrome..69i57.5385j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Parse the `Strings` into either a `Calendar` object or `LocalDateTime` object then use `.compareTo()`...

Comment: Start with the [Java Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). Here's the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Note that LocalDateTime instances are Comparable.

Comment: @Lashane - The input data is for just 1 week always, so that's why need to be sorted that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309558/time-comparison)

Comment: Which day is the first day of your week? The international standard says the week begins on Monday, but not all countries observe it,

Comment: @AmitGarg Please take more care in drafting your post. As it reads now your Question does not make sense. And post further information as edits to the Question rather than as Comments. Do not make your readers work so hard as to trawl through the threads of comments to understand your issue.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to build a little class to represent the times. We could call it `TimeOfWeek` or `WeeklyRecurringEvent` or whatever fits your domain, please try to choose wisely. The class would have two instance fields, a `DayOfWeek` for the weekday and a `LocalTime` for the time. `DayOfWeek` and `LocalTime` are in `java.time` (introduced in Java 8 and backported to Java 6 and 7). My class would have a constructor accepting a `String` argument like `"Friday 2:00 PM"` and would parse it into the two instance fields. The same `DateTimeFormatter` could be used for both, so this could be a class constant (private static final field). `DayOfWeek` does not have a `parse` method, so you would need something like `DayOfWeek.from(yourDateTimeFormatter.parse(yourString))`. There’s a short demonstration in code below.

Your class should implement `Comparable` so you can sort your objects by their natural order. In your `compareTo` method compare day of week first, then time if day is the same. `DayOfWeek`are sorted naturally from Monday to Sunday; if your week begins on another day than Monday, you will need to handle it specially.

Your class could also have a `ZoneId` field for time zone, but assuming all your times are in the same time zone, there’s probably no reason.

You may also see if you can find a class that fits your requirements somewhere out there; use your search engine. I don’t know of one, but you can never tell.

The classes in `java.time` are very often good for funny requirements about day and time. You can obviously have a date without a time or a time without a date. You can have a day of the year without a year (good for remembering your anniversary) and as mentioned a day of week without a week, and more. Unfortunately there isn’t a class to match your requirement of day of week and time exactly, which is why I suggest putting it together from two of the existing classes.

If programming for older Android (API level under 26/Oreo), use java.time through desugaring (link below).

#### Code

Edit: Parsing your strings into both a `DayOfWeek` and a `LocalTime` can be done in many ways. Here’s one:

```
    DateTimeFormatter weekTimeFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);

    TemporalAccessor parsed = weekTimeFormatter.parse("Friday 2:00 PM");
    DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from(parsed);
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.from(parsed);

    System.out.format(Locale.US, "Day: %s; time: %s.%n", dow, time);
```

Output from the snippet is:

> Day: FRIDAY; time: 14:00.

#### Links

- [Trail: Date Time (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in Android developer documentation.

Comment: All good suggestions! A bit more explanation is required to suggest how to handle the input string e.g. `Friday 2:00 PM Thursday 2:00 AM Saturday 4:00 PM`. There can be many ways (e.g. regex) to separate them into combinations of weekday and time.