# How to compare time in Java LocalTime?

Tags: java, compare, equals, localtime

Given two [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) parameters in Java, I want to be able to compare the two times and see if they are equal (the same time). How would I do this?

Comment: Uh.. call `equals()`?

Comment: You could start by reading the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) or looking at the [Date/Time Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309558/time-comparison)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
firstLocalTime.equals(secondLocalTime);
```

`.equals()` is available for all `Object`s in Java.

Answer (score 10):

Compare using `LocalTime` instance methods: [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore(java.time.LocalTime)), [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isAfter(java.time.LocalTime)), [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), and [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#compareTo(java.time.LocalTime)).

```
LocalTime lt1 = LocalTime.of( 14 , 17 ) ;
LocalTime lt2 = LocalTime.of( 21 , 29 ) ;

boolean same = lt1.equals( lt2 ) ;
```

## `equals` versus `isEqual`

Be aware than some *java.time* classes (other than `LocalTime`) carry an `isEqual` method in addition to the `equals` method inherited from `Object`, with different semantics.

For example:

- [`LocalDate.isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isEqual(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)) versus [`LocalDate.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#equals(java.lang.Object))
- [`ZonedDateTime.isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isEqual(java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime)) versus [`ZonedDateTime.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#equals(java.lang.Object))