# Compare Two time in String

Tags: java

I am trying to compare my string time in format of (HH:SS)

String timestart= 08:00
String timeend= 21:00

I am trying to build my code and logic but I am not sure whether my comparison of time is correct I wanted to check whether this two time strings are under the condition of timestart will be greater than or
equal 06:00 am and timeend less than or equal 22:00

code

```
int endday = Integer.parseInt(time_to); 
int startday = Integer.parseInt(time_start);

if ((startday >= '06:00') && (startday  <= '22:00')) &&
((endday  >= '06:00') && (endday  <= '22:00'))  {
System.out.print("passed");

}else{

System.out.print("no");

}
```

Comment: `Time` is not an `int`. `parseInt` is wrong here.

Comment: Additionally, single quotation marks are exclusively for `Characters`. Not `String`s. (Error). There's more. Even if that were a String (can't possibly be an integer with the `:` char) you can't compare `Integers` to `Strings` like that. (Error) Please try compiling your code and look for compiling errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309558/time-comparison)

Comment: It's not really, his actual problem is the compiling errors. There are... 6.

Comment: Agree, @FailingCoder. It’s still a very helpful link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java 8 Date/Time api,

```
`DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
String time_start = "08:00";
String time_to = "22:00";
if (LocalTime.parse(time_start, formatter).
                    isAfter(LocalTime.parse("06:00", formatter)) && 
                    LocalTime.parse("21:00", formatter).
                    isBefore(LocalTime.parse(time_to, formatter)))  {
    System.out.print("passed");
}else{
    System.out.print("no");
}`
```

**Output**
`passed`

[readmore](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Vimukthi_R is helpful in showing you the right library class and methods to use and is almost correct. So my version is similar, but I would like to show you a few twists.

```
    LocalTime minTime = LocalTime.of(6, 0);
    LocalTime maxTime = LocalTime.of(22, 0);

    String timeStart = "08:00";
    String timeEnd = "21:00";
    LocalTime startDay = LocalTime.parse(timeStart);
    LocalTime endDay = LocalTime.parse(timeEnd);

    if (startDay.isBefore(minTime)
            || endDay.isBefore(startDay)
            || endDay.isAfter(maxTime)) {
        System.out.print("no");
    } else {
        System.out.print("passed");
    }
```

Since you want to accept start and end times in the interval frmo 6 to 22 *inclusive*, `isBefore` and `isAfter` don’t really give you the exact answer. We would have needed methods `isBeforeOrOn` and `isOnOrAfter`, but they don’t exist. Rather than writing auxiliary methods for that purpose, I am turning the whole logic upside-down: if the start time is *before* 6 or the end time *after* 22, the validation fails.

For defining 6 and 22 as `LocalTime` objects parsing strings works, but my taste is more for the `of` method (please make your own pick).

For parsing we don’t need a formatter since your strings are in the standard ISO 8601 format that `LocalTime` parses as its default. One may of course prefer the formatter since it makes the format explicit in the code. Again pick your own preference.

I was assuming that end time could not be before start time, which simplified the condition to three sub-conditions instead of four. If you didn’t want this, I am trusting you to write out the four subconditions.

> I am not sure whether my comparison of time is correct

No, your comparison was not correct. In Java you can use `>=` and `<=` for comparing numbers, but not strings or or other objects like `LocalTime`. Also, as Johannes Kuhn said in a comment, you cannot parse a string like `08:00` into an integer. FallingCoder said the rest in a comment:

> Additionally, single quotation marks are exclusively for Characters.
>   Not Strings.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.