# How to Compare Two time(12 hours format) in android

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I have two times, that come from the database. one time is 11:04 AM and another time is 1:00 PM. now how can i compare like this

```
 if(11:04 AM < 1:00 PM){
   // code is here
  }else{
   //Code is here
   }
```

Comment: First convert time into milliseconds and then compare them.

Comment: @Shane please suggest me some reference link to convert milliseconds. the time format is that i mention before

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309558/time-comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String s1 = "11:04 AM";
    String s2 = "1:00 PM";
    LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse(s1, timeFormatter);
    LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.parse(s2, timeFormatter);
    if (time1.isBefore(time2)) {
        System.out.println("time1 < time2");
    } else {
        System.out.println("time1 >= time2");
    }
```

Output from this snippet is:

> time1 < time2

The snippet shows how to parse your time strings into `LocalTime` objects and compare them using `isBefore`. There are also methods `isEqual` and `isAfter`. However, even better. store your times as `time` datatype in your SQL database and retrieve `LocalTime` objects directly from your database and avoid the parsing.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

there is no User-defined operator overloading in java . 
  however you can try something like this:

```
  class mTime{

    int minute , hour;
    public mTime(int hour, int minute){
        this.minute = minute;
        this.hour = hour ;
    }
    public mTime(String time){
        this.hour = Integer.valueOf(time.substring(0,2));
        this.minute = Integer.valueOf(time.substring(3,5));

        if(time.charAt(6) == 'P'){
            hour = hour+12;
        }

    }
    public boolean isBiggerThan(mTime other)
    {
        if(this.hour>other.getHour())
            return true;
        if(this.hour == other.getHour()){
            if(this.minute > other.getMinute())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public int getMinute(){
        return minute;
    }
    public int getHour(){
        return hour;
    }
}
```