# Compare strings startTime and endTime with current time and perform action

Tags: java, android, time

I'm trying to make a function which I want to only work between given time.

i.e: If startTime is "13:00" and endTime is "14:00" then every day when the user uses my app at/between this time then call the function, else do nothing.

Here's what I came across while trying to figure out but this doesn't work.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.UK);

       try {
           Date inTime = sdf.parse("13:00");
           Date outTime = sdf.parse("14:00");
           if (outTime != null) {
               if (isTimeAfter(inTime, outTime)) {
                   Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Time validation success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               else {
                   Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Exit time must be greater then entry time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }
       } catch (ParseException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Parse error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }


public static boolean isTimeAfter(Date startTime, Date endTime) {
       return !endTime.before(startTime);
   }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE 1**:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.UK);
       Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

       try {
           Date inTime = sdf.parse("03:19");
           Date outTime = sdf.parse("03:21");

           if (now.after(inTime) && now.before(outTime)) {
               Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Time validation success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Nope, it isn't wokring", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       } catch (ParseException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Parse error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
```

Comment: "but this doesn't work" what does it do that you don't expect?

Comment: "`if (outTime != null) {`" when do you expect `outTime` to be `null`?

Comment: All this does is verify that your start and end times are valid. This doesn't do any comparison to the current time.

Comment: @TimRoberts exactly, this part is done but I'm not sure how I can compare these values with local device time, hence the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309558/time-comparison)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalTime start = null ;
LocalTime end = null ;
try
{
    start = LocalTime.parse( "03:19" ) ;
    end = LocalTime.parse( "03:21" ) ;
} 
catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) 
{
    … handle faulty input
}

LocalTime currentTimeOfDay = LocalTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) ;
if( 
    ( ! currentTimeOfDay.isBefore( start ) )   // "Is not before …" is a briefer way of asking "Is equal to or later than …".
    &&
    currentTimeOfDay.isBefore( end )
)
{ … within target times }
else
{ … outside target times }
```

## Stop using `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat`

The [Answer by Yoni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66359196/642706) is close to being the right solution, but continues your confusion by using `java.util.Date` class. **Never use `java.util.Date`**, just stop, let it go, move on.

Those legacy date-time classes are a wretched mess. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community gave up on them years ago with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). So should you.

You said:

> i.e: If startTime is "13:00" and endTime is "14:00" then every day when the user uses my app at/between this time then call the function, else do nothing.

### `LocalTime`

Represent your start and end times.

```java
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of( 13 , 0 ) ;
LocalTime end = LocalTime.of( 14 , 0 ) ;
```

Capture the current moment as seen in a particular time zone.

### `ZoneId`

You can assume the user wants to use the JVM’s default time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

If critical, you should confirm with the user their intended time zone. Specify a [real time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) name using format of `Continent/Region`, never the 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `IST`, `EST`, `PST`, etc.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

With the time zone issue decided, capture the current moment as seen in that zone.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ) ;
```

Extract the time-of-day value from that moment.

```
LocalTime currentTimeOfDay = now.toLocalTime() ;
```

### Compare `LocalTime` objects

Compare with your target start-end.

Generally best to define spans of time using the Half-Open approach, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

```java
if( 
    ( ! currentTimeOfDay.isBefore( start ) )   // "Is not before …" is a briefer way of asking "Is equal to or later than …".
    &&
    currentTimeOfDay.isBefore( end )
)
{ … within target times }
else
{ … outside target times }
```

### Parsing

If you must obtain your start and end time-of-day values by parsing text in standard ISO 8601 format where the hour is 24-hour clock (0-23) and padding zeros are utilized, then simply call [`LocalTime.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) method. No need to specify a formatting pattern. No need to specify a `Locale`.

```java
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( "03:19" ) ;
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse( "03:21" ) ;
```

To protect against faulty inputs, trap for [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).

```java
LocalTime start = null ;
LocalTime end = null ;
try
{
    start = LocalTime.parse( "03:19" ) ;
    end = LocalTime.parse( "03:21" ) ;
} 
catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) 
{
    … handle faulty input
}
```

Comment: While your solution seems great the issue is compatibility. "LocalTime" requires API 26+ and my app supports devices running 21, hence the reason why I'm looking for a method that can run on all devices.

Comment: @StevenRõgrê The latest versions of Android tooling bring most of the *java.time* functionality to earlier Android via “API desugaring”.

Comment: I did mention in my anwser to use LocalTime, but you are correct it might be confusing as I put the Date version first. I've updated my anwser and only left the LocalTime example to avoid any confustion. It's also the way it should be used.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are comparing your 2 fixed dates. You check that 13:00 is after 14:00. Which is always going to be true.

What you want to compare to is the current time. You want the current time to be after the start time and before the end time.

As of java 8, it's also recommended to make use of `LocalTime` instead of `Date`. This solves a lot of issues you might encounter with timezones and such.

To get the current time, you could make use of `LocalTime.now()`.
The code snippet looks something like this then

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
now.isAfter(startTime) && now.isBefore(endTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and trying to help but it doesn't seem to work. 
Check my edit as to what I tried.